# Match substrings and extract strings based on conditional statements in Postgresql 11.0

Tags: postgresql

I have following table in postgres 11:

```
level1          level2      level3          level4          
A (alimentary)  A05 (bile)  A05C (drugs)    A01AA (caries)
A (alimentary)  A05 (bile)  A05C (drugs)    A01AA (caries)
A (alimentary)  A01 (bile)  A01AA (drugs)   A01AA (caries)
```

I would like add another column 'code' to the existing table, and copy the value of level4 to code if level1 is a substring of level2 and level2 is a substring of level3 and level3 is a substring of level4 (row2)
else copy the level3 value if level1 is a substring of level2 and level2 is a substring of level3 (row1)

```
level1          level2      level3          level4          code
A (alimentary)  A05 (bile)  A05C (drugs)    null            A05C
A (alimentary)  A01 (bile)  A01AA (drugs)   A01AA (caries)  A01AA
```

I am using following query to execute this:

```
SELECT level1.*,
               level2.*,
               level3.*,
               level4.*,
               case 
                   when (level1 like 'level2') and (level2 like 'level3') and (level3 like 'level4') then substring(atc_code_level4, 1, 5) 
                   when (level1 like 'level2') and (level2 like 'level3') then substring(atc_code_level3, 1, 4) 
                   else level2
               end as code
        FROM (SELECT * from level1) as level1, 
                (SELECT * from level2) as level2, 
                (SELECT * from level3) as level3,
                (SELECT * from level4) as level4
```

Comment: `SELECT * from level1` makes no sense if `level1` is a column. You can only select FROM **tables**

Answer (score 1):

You have several issues. First off given your input a strict application of your rules there is no query which gives your output - there is no null value in level4 and no rule to create it. Now lets analyze your input against your rules:  
In the following: Let the symbol E> mean "is a sub-string of". So A E> B E> C means A is a sub-string of B and B is a sub-string of C ... Let "symbol ==> VAL" mean if preceding conditions are true then generate output VAL. Then define as Code Leading characters in level up to 1st space (or any white space).

- R1: Each level must have a prefix code. Let each be CodeN where N corresponds to the column.
- R2: Code1 E> Code2 E> Code3 E> Codel4  ==> Code4  (given)
- R3: If Not Rule 2 and Code1 E> Code E> Code3 ==> Code3 (given)
- R4: If Not Rule 2 and Not Rule 2 ==> Code2 ( derived for your query).
- R5: Final output should not contain duplicated (derived from desired
  results).

Now your input:

- Row1: Satisfies R1 and R2 so outputs Code4
- Row2: Identical to Row 1 so output removed as it would be duplicate (R5)
- Row3: Satisfies R1 and R3 so outputs Code3.

---

Now for your query:
As a_horse_with_no_name pointed out you select from tables not columns. If levels are indeed columns then level.* is totally meaningless. You query used the LIKE predicate but without wildcards (% or _) but without them [LIKE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE) is the same a equal (=) and then you use a string literal. So your clause "where (level1 like 'level2')" says exactly the same as "where level1 = 'leval2'" and all rows would fail. Finally you use hard coded numeric values within your SUBSTRING function call, without specifying a fixed length rule, indeed the data in Row2 and Row3 demonstrate the lengths are NOT fixed.

---

What you need to do.  
Unrelated to this specific question you need to spend some learning the basic SQL components. What are the structural elements? What is purpose of each element? How to combine these elements into complete/composite whole?  
Unambiguously define each requirement. You should be able to write a simple declarative natural language sentence for each requirement. Clearly define inputs and outputs, and that applying the requirements map from input to output.  

**Specific to this question**: It seems the first thing is to separate the CODE out of from each line (level). Then validate that the E> requirements are satisfied. For this I suggest the variant of the [SUBSTRING](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-substring/) that takes a regular expression for extraction. Then use the [POSITION](https://www.w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/position-function.php) function to verify which, if any, of the E> requirements are satisfied. This can all be accomplished with a single SQL statement. See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=dfdb90ecb71f07905b3203157b8c7e8d).

```
with regex(pattern) as 
     (values ('^.+\s'))
select distinct                                 -- R5
       level1
     , level2
     , level3 
     , level4     
     , case when position (l1s in l2s) = 1      -- R2
             and position (l2s in l3s) = 1
             and position (l3s in l4s) = 1
            then l4s                            -- R3                  
            when position (l1s in l2s) = 1
             and position (l2s in l3s) = 1
            then l3s
            else l2s                            -- R4
       end code      
 from (Select g1.* 
         from (elect level1
                   , level2
                   , level3
                   , level4 
                   -- extract the CODE from each level 
                   , trim(substring(level1, pattern)) l1s 
                   , trim(substring(level2, pattern)) l2s 
                   , trim(substring(level3, pattern)) l3s 
                   , trim(substring(level4, pattern)) l4s    
                from test cross join regex   
               where level1 ~ pattern           --  R1
                 and level2 ~ pattern
                 and level3 ~ pattern
                 and level4 ~ pattern 
              ) g1 
          where position (g1.l1s in g1.l2s) = 1
      ) gl2;
```